# change color of BarBackgroundColor

Tags: xamarin, background, xamarin.android, themes, xamarin.forms

How do I change the color of the "BackgroundColorBar" in runtime?, what happens is that I want to change the color as if it were a theme, which the user can choose a color and this change.

Its for Xamarin.Forms

Answer (score 0):

In your ContentPage properties, you can add a NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor and NavigationPage.BarTextColor which then you can bind to so that you can change them on runtime. (Be sure to set the NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar to true)

Ex:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="MyClass.Views.MyView" NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar="true" NavigationPage.BarBackgroundColor="{Binding BindingHandlerHere}">
```

Comment: interesting... however, there's I couldn't find a property called NavigationPage accessible from the ContentPage code behind or xaml. Have you actually tried this? What am I missing?